# Is there a way to use "wait_for message" in "on_raw_reaction_add" in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a function that changes the user's nickname if he clicks on a specific emoji and prints his new nickname.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji
    author = payload.member
    if channel.id == channel_test_id:
        def check(m):
            return m.author == ???.author
        await channel.send("Enter your new nickname")
        msg2 = await bot.wait_for("message", check = check)
        await author.edit(nick = msg2.content)
```

So, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```py
def check(m):
    return m.author == payload.member # Or simply `author` cause you made a variable like that
```

Note: `payload.member` can be `None` if the event it's not called inside a guild.

Read about the attributes [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.RawReactionActionEvent)